# Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in Facade.php:258 when upgrading to Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-facade

I got the error regarding facade even though I followed the laravel upgrade guide

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in D:\Git_Undiksha\legalisir-ijasah-online\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Faca
des\Facade.php:258
Stack trace:
#0 D:\Git_Undiksha\legalisir-ijasah-online\app\Exceptions\Handler.php(39): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('error', Array)
#1 D:\Git_Undiksha\legalisir-ijasah-online\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(366): App\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(Error))
#2 D:\Git_Undiksha\legalisir-ijasah-online\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(131): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->reportException
(Object(Error))
#3 D:\Git_Undiksha\legalisir-ijasah-online\artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Compo
nent\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#4 {main}
  thrown in D:\Git_Undiksha\legalisir-ijasah-online\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 258

Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in D:\Git_Undiksha\legalisir-ijasah-online\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\F
acade.php:258
Stack trace:
#0 D:\Git_Undiksha\legalisir-ijasah-online\app\Exceptions\Handler.php(39): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('error', Array)
#1 D:\Git_Undiksha\legalisir-ijasah-online\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(366): App\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(Error))
#2 D:\Git_Undiksha\legalisir-ijasah-online\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(131): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->reportException
(Object(Error))
#3 D:\Git_Undiksha\legalisir-ijasah-online\artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Compo
nent\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#4 {main}
  thrown in D:\Git_Undiksha\legalisir-ijasah-online\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 258
```

Facade.php:258

```
public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
{
    $instance = static::getFacadeRoot();

    if (! $instance) {
        throw new RuntimeException('A facade root has not been set.');
    }

    return $instance->$method(...$args);
}
```

Here is my composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.2.5",
    "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
    "facade/ignition": "^2.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "composer/composer": "^1.10",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.1"
},
```

I did change the Handler.php Exception to Throwable, session.php secure env from false to null, and set any handle() command return to integer.

How do I solve the facade error and what should I do?

Comment: How you tried clearing config and cache, then doing composer update again?           `php artisan config:cache`
`php artisan config:clear`
`php artisan cache:clear`
 `composer update`

Comment: @Nathan I tried them but the facade error showed instead

Comment: What version are you upgrading from?

Comment: @jgetner from Laravel 6, but I can't check the exact version anymore, now I'm in Laravel 7 (php artisan --version would reproduce the facade error too)

Comment: Run composer update and then composer dump-autoload in console window.

Comment: @jgetner I still got the error

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/laravel download the config and add to your config.

Comment: does your bootstrap/app.php contain withFacades? and its commented out?

Comment: @jgetner the new config is still doesn't work, there is no commented single line like withFacades in bootstrap/app.php

Comment: @jgetner Finally I solved it on my own! too bad I can't accept my own answer ("You can accept your own answer in 2 days")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making a new working Laravel version 7 project, copy the app and config folders to the new one (for testing purpose), renaming a file and then testing with `php artisan --version` every changes I made (rename each no-numbered files to (1) and (2) files to no-numbered), finally I found out what is the problem: config/excel.php

in excel.php I commented autosize-method and it works!

```
// 'autosize-method'             => PHPExcel_Shared_Font::AUTOSIZE_METHOD_APPROX,
```